# How to access the value of a data attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery, custom-attributes

I want to access the data attribute in jQuery.
but every time I try to access it it returns undefined.

code is

```
<select name="start" id="source">
    <option selected disabled>Select your location</option>
    <option data-lat="74.1833" value="some for php">Gujranwala</option>
    <option data-lat="74.3436" value="some for php">Lahore</option>
    <option data-lat="74.536" value="some for php">sialkot</option>
    <option data-lat="74.0789" value="some for php">gujrat</option>
    <option data-lat="67.0100" value="some for php">Karachi</option>
  </select>
```

I tried using

```
$('#source').attr('data-lat');
```

when user select a option than it should give the custom attribute value.
but it is not working.. still get undefined.
can anyone show me any alternative solution or if i am wrong in this one please correct it...

try to submit the running example please..
thanks in advance.

if i do any thing wrong explaining the problem, please ignore that, i hope you guys got it what i am trying to say.. :)

Comment: you are looking for the val in the select tag and not in the option...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to target the selected option on which is set custom attribute. By the way, you could use [**`data()`**](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function.

```
$('#source option:selected').data('lat');
```

Comment: @UmerMehAr Updated answer.